# PowerBI - Best way to split column as new rows, enrich hose rows and then include on a report w/ the original data

Tags: powerbi

I'm trying to figure out the best way to enrich a table of orders with the country region (Americas, Asia, Europe, Africa, etc) when the country field has multiple concatenations of country in a single record. I know that I can split the column as new rows, but that would expand the length of the table dramatically, which could affect performance.

Target table example

| ID | Country | FieldA | FieldB | fields C-Z |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1. | United States;Taiwan;Hong Kong;Bermuda | abc | 123 | etc |
| 2. | Canada | qqq. | fvvv. | etc |
| 3. | Spain; Portugal; Australia | xxz | 1245 | etc |

What I've done so far within PowerQuery is taken a 'reference' of the target table and removed all columns except the 'order #' and 'country'. I then made some replacements in the reference table to fix some country names that aren't formatted to the correct ISO standard. E.g., 'Hong Kong' to 'Hong Kong S.A.R.'. I also merged that reference table with a dimension table of country_region.

So now the reference table looks like:

| ID | Country | FieldA | FieldB | Region |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1. | United States | 123 | abc | Americas |
| 1. | Taiwan | abc | 123 | Asia |
| 1. | Hong Kong S.A.R. | abc | 123 | Asia |
| 1. | Bermuda | abc | 123 | Other |
| 2. | Canada | qqq | fvvv. | Americas |
| 3. | Spain | xxz | 1245 | Europe |
| 3. | Portugal | xxz | 1245 | Europe |

This works quite well in a limited sense. I can plot the geo locations/order values from this reference table on a report along side other tables/fields. I also created measures for each Region so that I can plot them on a data card to show exposure:

```
countAfrica = Calculate ( 
  Count ( 'ref_tbl~ctry'[Order#] ), 
    Filter ( 
       All ( 'ref_tbl~ctry' ),
        ( 'ref_tbl~ctry'[dim-map.region ) = 'Africa'
```

However, when a user clicks one of the bubbles on the map, it doesn't filter other visuals or tables on the page where the source data is the original target table.

What's the best strategy for enriching a table of concatenated country strings with the region and plotting those on a map? Should I just split columns as new rows and enrich in the target table and then treat individual visualizations and tables individually? I.e., certain visuals would use count data irrespective of distinct order #s and certain fields would use distinct?

Open to all kinds of feedback here as I'm a new PBI developer. I'm reading Definitive DAX Guide, Ultimate PowqerQuery Cookbook, PowerBI Exam Prep book, endlessly consuming and excited to learn more!